# Equivalence in javascript of $name_function();

Tags: php, javascript

I want to create the name of my function javascript when load in browser and run it.

I want the equivalence of this php's code :

```
<?php

$name_function = 'toto';

function toto() {
    echo 'toto';
}


$name_function();

?>
```

My eval : the evil :)

```
var chaine = 'TabToto';
var store = chaine.substr(3,chaine.length);
eval ('store = this.get'+store+'Store()');
```

Ok , what i want :

```
var chaine = 'TabToto';
var store = 'get'+chaine.substr(3,chaine.length)+'Store';

store = this[store]();
```

My controller create a function to get a store and i want to use it ...

Comment: Sounds as if you're Doing It Wrong...

Answer (score 4):

```js
function toto()
{
    alert('toto');
}

var name_function  = 'toto';
window[name_function]();
```

(assuming this is in global scope)

Comment: and if my function is in me (this.getTotoStore) ?

Comment: Just avoid eval so you don't get into XSS problems.  In general, just use scope[myFunctionName].

Comment: Thx this[my_function_name] is ok!

Comment: Awesome.  Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of providing the name of the function as a string, you can also assign a reference to the function itself to a variable.

That would look like this:

```
function toto() {
    alert('toto');
}
function toto2() {
    alert('toto 2');
}

var function_to_use = toto;   // notice the lack of quotes
function_to_use();

function_to_use = toto2;
function_to_use();
```

Comment: not really what i want

Answer (score 0):

i have done like this

```
function a(){
alert(1);

}
var aa=a;

 aa();
```